# ValidationError match expression when using podAntiaffinity

Tags: kubernetes

deployments.apps was not valid:
Invalid value: "The edited file failed validation": [ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.affinity.podAntiAffinity.requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution[0]): unknown field "podAffinityTerm" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodAffinityTerm, ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.affinity.podAntiAffinity.requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution[0]): unknown field "weight" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodAffinityTerm, ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.affinity.podAntiAffinity.requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution[0]): missing required field "topologyKey" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodAffinityTerm]

```
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - podAffinityTerm:
              labelSelector:
                matchLabels:
                  app: xyz
                  tier: xyz-mongo
              topologyKey: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone
            weight: 1
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - podAffinityTerm:
              labelSelector:
                matchExpressions:
                - key: releaseName
                  operator: In
                  values:
                  - xyz-abc-mongo
              topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
            weight: 2
```

I am trying to launch selected labels pods over the node, so to have it running as **one pod over one node** but while I am using **requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution** so my pods didn't get evict, it is showing me template error.

Answer (score 0):

The items underneath `requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` do not accept a `weight` field and they also do not accept a `podAffinityTerm` field.

If you remove both fields, it should do the trick.

```
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - podAffinityTerm:
              labelSelector:
                matchLabels:
                  app: xyz
                  tier: xyz-mongo
              topologyKey: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone
            weight: 1
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - labelSelector:
                matchExpressions:
                - key: releaseName
                  operator: In
                  values:
                  - xyz-abc-mongo
              topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
```

Comment: deployments.apps was not valid:
Invalid value: "The edited file failed validation": [ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.affinity.podAntiAffinity.requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution[0]): unknown field "podAffinityTerm" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodAffinityTerm, ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.affinity.podAntiAffinity.requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution[0]): missing required field "topologyKey" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodAffinityTerm]



it is throwing me this error while removing weight

Comment: @AakarshitAgarwal yes, sorry about that. It turns out that also the field `podAffinityTerm` is not allowed in `requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution`. Please try with my edited answer and it should be working now.

Comment: The template is working fine but I am still not able to see get 1 pod over 1 node.
You have any idea about that?

Comment: Could you help me better understand your problem? How many nodes and pods do you have? And is there a specific reason why you want to use `podAffinity` instead of `nodeSelector` ?

Comment: I am trying to use `podantiaffinity` so that pods get scheduled on any node other than the label I specified, I don't have an issue with horizontal node scaling.
I am not using `nodeSelector` because I want to have more control over the pod eviction/scheduling over the nodes